# template class with STL container member

Tags: c++, templates, stl, visual-studio-2005

I'm writing a template class that uses a std::multimap as a member, and getting compile errors.

LocTree.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <map>

template <class Loc, class T>
class LocTree
{
public :
         typedef std::multimap<typename Loc, typename T> TreeType;

        LocTree( void );
        ~LocTree( void ) { };
private :
        TreeType db;
};
```

LocTree.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "LocTree.h"

LocTree< class Loc, class T>::LocTree()
{
}
```

The compile error (from VC2005) :

```
Error     1     error C2079: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::first' uses undefined class 'Loc'     c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility     53
Error     2     error C2079: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second' uses undefined class 'T'     c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility     54
```

I know I could put the function definitions in the .h but I'm hoping to keep them separate, if it's legal to do so.  How do I fix this (probably newbie) problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor definition should be:

```
template<class Loc, class T>
LocTree<Loc,T>::LocTree()
{
}
```

Also, hoping to keep them separate... - don't - you're wasting your time. The only way to keep them separate is to have a definition in a different header which you also include. So, technically, they are separate, but the implementation is still visible.

Comment: Unless you want to export explicit instantiations for specific combinations of `Loc`and `T`

Comment: @JohannesS. ah yes. But even then you have to at least declare them in the header.

Comment: (It should also be in the header file.)

Comment: Having the definition in a different header can be very advantageous actually, although a lot depends on whether the implementation includes other headers you don't want to see in general.

Comment: good point about needing to keep the definition visible ... I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

Two points.  The first is: what is:

```
typedef std::multimap<typename Loc, typename T> TreeType;
```

supposed to mean?  I don't see what the `typename` are doing in there; I
think you just want:

```
typedef std::multimap<Loc, T> TreeType;
```

Second, when defining a member function of a class template outside of the
class, the syntax is:

```
template <typename Loc, typename T>
LocTree<Loc, T>::LocTree()
{
}
```

In other words, you have to repeat the `template<...>` clause.  (Whether
you use `typename` or `class` in the `<...>` is indifferent.  Since it
doesn't have to be a class, Most people I know prefer `typename`, since
this corresponds closer to what is meant.)

As for keeping the implementation separate: templates in C++ are
somewhat broken in this respect.  You can't avoid the compiler
dependency.  You still do want to keep the implementation separate from
the definition, however.  The usual technique is to put the template
implementation in a separate file (`.tcc`, for example), and include
this from the header.

Comment: The `typename`s are from my misguided attempts at fixing the compile error; the typedef is mostly to make it easier to declare iterators (I'm stuck with c++03, as you can see).

Comment: Are there practical reasons to put the implementation in the separate file though? (I wanted it that way mainly for clarity.)

Comment: @martin_ljchan Just basic good engineering principles.  You don't want the definition of the client interface in the same file as your implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the implementation of a template separate is not a trivial thing to do.

In general it cannot be done. That is, it cannot be done where the templated parameters may be "anything".

For a specific limited subset of templated parameters it is possible to do, for example if you have a template like:

```
template< bool B > class Foo;
```

You can then specify:

```
extern template class Foo<true>;
extern template class Foo<false>;
```

and this is called "instantiating" the templates, and specifying to the compiler that there are implementations for values true and false, implemented elsewhere.

This can also be done where the templated parameters are types and are limited to a specific subset.

Within the compilation unit you then define the template implementations and then instantiate the templates once again using the same as above but without the word "extern".

I have done this in production code in a case where you are creating a member function to set a parameter value for a database stored-procedure call where only a very limited subset of parameter types are permitted. If your types are a very limited subset then go ahead and do the same if this helps decouple the code and hide a lot of implementation detail (in the case where the implementation is then done in a database, it is well worth doing).

There is an "in-between" ground where you provide the implementation in another header, often I have seen `_i.h` or similar for this convention and then you instantiate the templates in ones, including this header only when necessary. Thus if you create a class Foo then in the header use the "extern" declaration for my foo class in `Foo.h` and in `Foo.cpp`, `#include` the `_i.h` file for the implementation and the instantiation.

As for the syntax, in the template implementation file use:

```
template<class Loc, class T>
LocTree<Loc,T>::method(...)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not trivial indeed! Thanks for sharing your experience, I'll keep it in mind in case I need it in the future.